# resource handler Spring exception: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, resources

I've been searching and searching, but can't find a proper sollution for the exception I'm getting. I'm building a web app with java, spring mvc, hibernate & MySQL. I've used Spring Security, because only authorized users are allowed to use the web app. I'm using css (bootstrap) to make it look good, but here is the problem, when accessing the resources I get the following exception:

```
    aug 25, 2016 10:41:38 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ToolManagementSystem/admin/resources/css/alfen.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
aug 25, 2016 10:41:38 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ToolManagementSystem/admin/resources/img/logo.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
aug 25, 2016 10:41:38 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ToolManagementSystem/admin/resources/css/bootstrap.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

The only way (I found so far) to prevent this to explicitely code every path in my resourcehandler

```
// Grants access to resources
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Here is my security-config

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('DBA')")
    .antMatchers("/lead/**").access("hasRole('LEAD')")
    .antMatchers("/responsible/**").access("hasRole('RESPONSIBLE')")
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
    .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().csrf()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}
```

Cheers, guys, for helping me out/pointing me in the right direction! (My apologies if this turns out a duplicate question)

solutions I've tried out are:

```
// Grants access to resources
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {      
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**/resources/**".addResourceLocations("/resources/)"
    }
```

and several ways of changing security configs, but I am open to all ideas/suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a little more fooling arround in my code. I've found the answer to my question and it turned out to be pretty simple.

Before my link to the resources in the jsp's looked like this:

```
<link href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="resources/css/alfen.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

Wich was not what it was supposed to be. This is what has made all the difference:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/alfen.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

And now it's working perfectly. So for completion I thought of posting this as one of the possible sollutions, when you might encouter the same problem!